Mi página no permite registrar ninguna acción en la base de datos desde la última actualización de MySQL y MariaDB
Tengo una web desde hace 18 años que creé sin conocimientos de programación dado que usé un CMS antiguo para la gestión y administración de sus contenidos. No han sido pocos los problemas que han surgido a lo largo de los últimos años, pero forzando una versión antigua de PHP a través del selector que me facilita el CPanel me había permitido capear el temporal. Sin embargo, las últimas actualizaciones de MySQL y MariaDB sí me han ocasionado una serie de problemas que de momento no soy capaz de solucionar.
La primera de ellas se produjo en mayo, lo cual me obligó a cambiar el conjunto de caracteres para adaptarlo al del servidor (de latin1_swedish_ci/ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8). De hecho, tuve que hacerlo de manera un tanto artesanal, ya que el cambio en el archivo php.ini sí hacía que los contenidos dinámicos (noticias, artículos y foros) fueran legibles, pero no así los estáticos (nombres de módulos y bloques, así como su información). Por lo tanto, para estos últimos me vi obligado a cambiar a mano los caracteres especiales (tildes, eñes y signos de apertura de interrogación y exclamación) por su código en bruto para que se mostraran correctamente.
En cambio, la última actualización llevaba a cabo por mi servidor a finales de julio ha traído consigo que la página se siga mostrando sin errores aparentes, pero no permitiendo el registro en las tablas de la base de datos de ninguna acción llevada a cabo a través de la web. Dejo algunos ejemplos a continuación:

Registro y logueo de usuarios.
Publicación de mensajes en foros, así como la vista previa.
Búsquedas.
Ordenar usuarios o cualquier otro contenido por cualquier criterio.
Cambios de información, ya sea en perfil o en cualquier otro apartado de la web.
Publicación de noticias, análisis o artículos.

En definitiva, la base de datos sí lee la web, pero no permite que se escriba en ella a través de la propia página. Y ya no sólo a los usuarios, sino a mí como administrador.
Curiosamente, si accedo a la base de datos vía phpmyadmin e intento cambiar la información de cualquier contenido o añadir cualquier otro nuevo (noticias, artículos, usuarios, etc.), sí me lo permite. Es decir, entiendo que el problema viene dado cuando la llamada a la base de datos se produce a partir de php.
Comparto a continuación los datos relativos a la última actualización que ha provocado este problema para que se sepa de qué versión a qué otra se ha pasado:
Servidor de base de datos: 10.6.18-MariaDB
Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode
cpsrvd: 11.120.0.8
Versión del cliente de la base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.28
Extensión PHP: mysqli curl mbstring
Versión de PHP: 8.1.28
Servidor de base de datos: 10.6.19-MariaDB
Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode
cpsrvd: 11.120.0.14
Versión del cliente de la base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.3.8
Extensión PHP: mysqli curl mbstring
Versión de PHP: 8.3.8
Dada mi inexperiencia, desconozco qué tipo de código puedo mostrar por aquí para que sirva de ayuda, así que si me orientáis un poco sobre ello podría ofreceros aquello que necesitéis.
Gracias anticipadas.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No se que tipo de CMS usas, pero me parece que lo primero que tenes que revisar son los logs, para ver que tipo de error estas recibiendo. Y segundo, ya ya deberias estar migrando todo a algo mas moderno. Las cosas muy viejas empiezan a sufrir problemas de agujeros de seguridad, los cuales te pueden traer otros problemas...

Muchas gracias por los consejos, los cuales son muy bien recibidos. El CMS que uso es PHP-Nuke, encontrándome con el problema de que no me es posible migrar a algo más moderno debido a la estructura de la web, ya que perdería muchas secciones que a día de hoy son fundamentales. De hecho, ya me estuve informando sobre Drupal, Joomla y otra serie de CMS sin que ninguno de ellos me ofrezca una solución viable que no me haga perder el 75% de mi página en lo que a contenidos y secciones se refiere.

En cuanto a los logs, los he revisado con ayuda de algún que otro experto en la materia y no arrojan ninguno que esté relacionado con este problema. Incluso he llegado a permitir que la web muestre errores en pantalla por si servía de ayuda, pero ninguno de ellos ofrecía información alguna que fuera de utilidad.

Sin toda esa informacion, mas que nuestra ayuda, vas a necesitar la ayuda de un profesional que revise paso a paso que se puede hacer para tratar de solucionar tu inconveniente.. este sitio ayuda con problemas de programacion concretos. Lo tuyo, sin mas informacion, parece ser un problema que requiere ayuda experta en el sitio...

Hola. Los logs de errores deberían estar escribiendo información valiosa de lo que está ocurriendo. Para casos como el que expones serían de hecho la mejor herramienta para ayudarte a modernizar totalmente tu código. Dudo mucho que no haya nada en ellos. Verifica que estás revisando el o los archivos correctos (teniendo en cuenta que un archivo de esos puede tener miles y miles de líneas) o si la escritura de errores está apagada en tu entorno de servidor, en cuyo caso debes encenderla.

Si ningún CMS más nuevo se amolda a tus necesidades, tendrás que hacerlo tu mismo, sugiero actualizarte con tecnologías más modernas. Si quieres trabajar en PHP, pues toma un curso de PHP 8, y luego un framework como Laravel y no estaría de más saber Javascript y algún framework del lado del cliente como React o Angular. Si te embarcas en ese proyecto, separa el backend del frontend (API REST), eso hará que la aplicación sea más fácil de mantener, incluso de desplegar en distintos entornos (web y aplicación móvil).
